# VMSizeDoesntSupportPremiumStorage Azure Creating VM From VHD

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using this template to create an Azure VM from an existing disk.

I'm using the EXACT same VM size "Standard_D11_v2" that the existing disk was created on, however I keep receiving the error listed below.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, I can't seem to get past this and I'm confused why I could originally have Standard_D11_V2 VM running this exact disk, but now I cannot.

**Error response**

```
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "VMSizeDoesntSupportPremiumStorage",
        "message": "Storage account type Premium_LRS is not supported for VM size Standard_D11_v2."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Here is my script:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "osDiskVhdUri": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Uri of the existing VHD"
            }
        },
        "osType": {
            "allowedValues": [
                "Windows",
                "Linux"
            ],
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Type of OS on the existing vhd"
            }
        },
        "vmSize": {
            "defaultValue": "Standard_A2",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Size of the VM"
            }
        },
        "vmName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the VM"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "diagStorageAccountName": "[concat(uniquestring(resourceGroup().id), 'specvm')]",
        "api-version": "2015-06-15",
        "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
        "subnetName": "Subnet",
        "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
        "publicIPAddressName": "specializedVMPublicIP",
        "publicIPAddressType": "Dynamic",
        "virtualNetworkName": "specializedVMVNET",
        "vnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/',variables('subnetName'))]",
        "nicName": "specializedVMNic"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_GRS"
            },
            "kind": "Storage",
            "name": "[variables('diagStorageAccountName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('api-version')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('api-version')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
                            },
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('api-version')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('api-version')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'-osDisk')]",
                        "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "vhd": {
                            "uri": "[parameters('osDiskVhdUri')]"
                        },
                        "createOption": "Attach"
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": "true",
                        "storageUri": "[concat(reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('diagStorageAccountName')), '2016-01-01').primaryEndpoints.blob)]"
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Here is where I found the above script:**

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a Premium Storage account for the VHD, but a VM size that does not support Premium Storage.  You have a couple choices to solve the issue:

1. Move the VHD to a standard storage account and use that storage account in your ARM template.
2. Use one of the DS size VMs that supports Premium Storage, such as Standard_DS11_v2.

You can read more about this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-premium-storage.

Comment: Thanks - stupid mistake on my part, was trying to use "Standard_D11_v2" instead of "Standard_DS11_v2"